# Cron: Import data from a service to MongoDB (Meteor)

Tags: mysql, mongodb, meteor, cron

I need an advice. I have two websites, one done with MySQL and a second, I am building with Meteor.

I need to get the data from the MySQL one every day or so and import it into the Meteor one.

The idea that comes to me was to create a service from the first site which offers the data as JSON at some endpoint (I would prefer this over connecting directly to MySQL since I want to separate clearly the two projects). The meteor site gets the data from this endpoint and insert it in MongoDB.

But, I don't know how to make the glue between the two:

- use of a cron like https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron (but I don't understand what will trigger the cron)
- use of crontab by creating an executable (which will be external to the Meteor site which bothers me in some ways since it would mean it would be outside the Meteor project
- another solution?

I have not a deep understanding of how Meteor works, so what would be the best solution for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With synced-cron time itself triggers the cron. You specify the interval at which you want the cron to run and then it runs forever by itself, that's the whole principle.

1. Expose a REST service from app1
2. Write a server-side js function in app2 that gets data from that REST endpoing
3. Call this function in a cron that runs daily, hourly, etc...
4. Make sure you can handle failures, for example the cron fails to run or the REST endpoing is down and the sync has to "catch up" the next day
5. Make sure you don't double-import data

Comment: Thank you! If I understand you, I have to create a server method using http and trigger it from synced cron?

Comment: Correct. Use the http package to get the resource.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will do this and upvote for you as soon as I get it to work

Comment: it's working! forgot about this, I finally upvoted for your answer!

Comment: Merci bien Louis quatorze.